# Submit a form with an additional POST var (NO AJAX)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is possible to submit a from (synchronous normal classic way, no AJAX) with an additional POST var?

Using AJAX is easy:

```
$("#cpa").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    newvalues = { name: "John", time: "2pm" }; 
    $.post(theurl, newvalues);
});
```

But i like to know if can SUBMIT (so the page reloads or goes to theurl) the form with additional data.

EDIT: Since there is a confusion on the comments, ill like to share more code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4zc4d/

Each time you click save the content of the alert is what i want to add to the form vars.

Comment: add a hidden field in your form....

Comment: @pXL How can i update the hidden field? because the new variable i want to add is generated dynamically. Please check the edit i made on the question.

Comment: hidden fields is how things where made before AJAX

Comment: edited my answer according to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add the hidden input via jQuery if you want to:

```
$("#cpa").submit(function(e) {
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="theName" value="some value" />');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="Norway">
```

as seen in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) to submit fields that the user shall not see. 
Beware: If the user cares to check sourcecode or traffic, he can find out the values.

EDIT:
About the additional fields in the jsfiddle: Did you realise you can send arrays directly?

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="2">
 <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="3">
```

will result in

```
$_POST['id'] = array(1,2,3)
```

No need to concat values.

Comment: FWIW, w3schools is a bad reference, littered with inaccuracies; see http://www.w3fools.com/ and consider using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ in future ;).

Comment: @Matt, thanks for the info, +1. Aside from that, the source is valid for that question, and Mozilla is not W3C either :)

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned, add a hidden field to your form HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidValue" />
```

Set the value required.

```
$("#hidValue").val("Anyvalue");
```